# limited float decimal point without rounding the number

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, rounding, decimal-point

I want convert a number to a float number with 3 decimal point but I want it without rounding.
For example:

```
a = 12.341661
print("%.3f" % a)
```

This code return this number:

```
12.342
```

but I need to original number,I need this:

```
12.341
```

> I write a code that receive a number form user and convert it to a float number.
>   I have no idea that what is the number entered with user.

Comment: You could use string manipulation instead of treating it as a number.

Comment: I search stack over flow but could not find my answer.
I found just about How to truncating but my Q is How truncating without rounding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought was to change `print("%.3f" % a)` to `print("%.3f" % (a-0.0005))` but it does not quite work: while it outputs what you want for a=12.341661, if a=12.341 it outputs 12.340, which is obviously not right.

Instead, I suggest doing the flooring explicitly using `int()`:

```
a = 12.341661
b = int(a*1000)/1000.
print(b)
```

This outputs what you want:

```
12.341
```

To get 3 decimals out even if the input has fewer, you can format the output:

```
a = 3.1
b = int(a*1000)/1000.
print("%.3f" % b)
```

Outputs:

```
3.100
```

Comment: it is good but if user enter 1.1 the code return 1.1 too.
but I want 3 decimal means 1.100

Comment: Just updated my answer to always output 3 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

try str and slicing

```
a = 12.341661
b = str(int(a))
c = str(a - int(a))[1:5]
d = b + c
print(d)
```

Comment: I have no idea that what is the number entered by user.
maybe the number with 10 digit entered.
For example:
12023.1288767

Comment: I edited my post to show you how you can get the number before the decimal and the 3 digits after the decimal

Comment: Doesn't work for negative numbers.

Comment: My inputs are all positive.
I think it,s best answer to my Q.